# Check out files from TFS from a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, tfs, tfs-sdk

I've read several posts here about replacing the obsolete `TeamFoundationServer` with `TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory` but not in a web service.  The obsolete method works in my web service but the `TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory` method does not.  It always throws an exception setting the workspace variable:

> There is no working folder mapping for C:\MyPath

The web service uses an app pool assigned to my identity which is a local machine admin and the new method works if I make it a console app.

Is it doable to replace `TeamFoundationServer` in a web service?

```
void TfsCheckout(string tfsServer, string wkSpace, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        //new method
        var pc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsServer));
        var versionControlServer = (VersionControlServer)pc.GetService((typeof(VersionControlServer)));
        var workspace = versionControlServer.GetWorkspace(wkSpace);
        var result = workspace.PendEdit(fileName);

        //obsolete method
        var tfs = new TeamFoundationServer(tfsServer, new UICredentialsProvider());
        var versionControl = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
        var workspc = versionControl.GetWorkspace(Environment.MachineName, versionControl.AuthenticatedUser);
        result = workspc.PendEdit(fileName);

        UpdateStatus(new UpdateStatusEventArgs("Checkout: " + fileName));
        UpdateStatus(new UpdateStatusEventArgs("Result: " + result + " (1=success 0=fail)"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        UpdateStatus(new UpdateStatusEventArgs(ex.ToString()));
        UpdateStatus(new UpdateStatusEventArgs("Done"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Added the AuthorizedUser property to my GetWorkspace and got it working:

    `var pc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsServer));
    var versionControlServer =     (VersionControlServer)pc.GetService((typeof(VersionControlServer)));
    var workspace = versionControlServer.GetWorkspace(Environment.MachineName, versionControlServer.AuthorizedUser);
var result = workspace.PendEdit(fileName);`

Comment: That solved it for me! Thanks